# The data returned from the api is always nil?

Tags: swift, api, httprequest, urlsession

I'm retrieving data from an API. The problem is the data always returns as nil.
It is a list of questions, usually 10. The code I wrote always returns 10 nil results. I tried the same code with different APIs with the same structure and it always works.

This is the struct:

```
struct Questions: Codable{
    let question: String?
}
```

This is the code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://adminsapi.somee.com/Api/Test/?id=1") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let test = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Questions].self, from: data)
            for ask in test{
                print(ask.question)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

This is the result I get:

```
nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil
```

This is the data returned from the API in postman:

```
[
    {
        "AskName": "Urgenct of defecation"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Mucous and streaked stools"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "vomiting"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Fever"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Tympany on percussion"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Bowel sounds"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "shifting dullness"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "psoas and obturator sign"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "rebound tenderness"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "signs of shock"
    }
]
```

Also, when I try to parse the json and read the whole data in one string, it works completely fine. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Never `try? JSONDecoder()`. Add a `do - catch` block and `print` the `error`  instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong. Hint: The data at the given URL is not JSON.

Comment: @vadian I think they were using a placeholder URL in the question. The JSON in the question, the one they say they received from Postman, is valid JSON.

Comment: @vadian I tried the do - catch and printing the error but it never throws any errors

Comment: You have to remove the question mark after `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Question` implementation is wrong. You need to tell the compiler that the `question` variable needs to be decoded using the `AskName` key.

```
struct Questions: Codable {
    let question: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case question = "AskName"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited.  Your Question struct is incorrect.  Here's working playground code that correctly parses the results.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let data = """
[
    {
        "AskName": "Urgenct of defecation"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Mucous and streaked stools"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "vomiting"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Fever"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Tympany on percussion"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "Bowel sounds"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "shifting dullness"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "psoas and obturator sign"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "rebound tenderness"
    },
    {
        "AskName": "signs of shock"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Questions: Codable{
    let AskName:String
}

do {
    try JSONDecoder().decode([Questions].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You could also define it as:

```
struct Questions: Codable {
    let question: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case question = "AskName"
    }
}
```